# Fingerprint recognition not working

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I am able to add a fingerprint either in Settings using GUI, or by `fprintd-enroll`. Both choices seem to work, the latter one outputs something like this:

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-retry-scan
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-retry-scan
Enroll result: enroll-retry-scan
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-completed
```

However, the fingerprint is NEVER correctly recognized. Trying `fprintd-verify` always leads to

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Listing enrolled fingers:
 - #0: right-index-finger
Verify started!
Verifying: right-index-finger
Verify result: verify-no-match (done)
```

What can I try to make the fingerprint recognition work correctly?

(I have dual booted Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.10 on Acer Aspire 5.)